# How do you make a static parse method that takes a string with tab-delimited parts?

Tags: java, eclipse

How can i get started. I know how to make this method but i dont know what exactly to put inside it.Im making a Song class that holds the year, rank of the song, artist, and title. I get this info from another txt file. The Song should have a static parse method that takes a string with tab-delimited parts and return a Song object. 
This is my code that I started with but I don't know if this is very legit. I also don't know if it really works properly either.

```
public class Billboard {
private int year;
private int rank;
private String artist;
private String title;


public void setYear(int Y){
    this.year = Y;
}
public void setRank(int R){
    this.rank = R;
}
public void setArtist(String A){
    this.artist = A;
}
public void setTitle(String T){
    this.title = T;
}
public int getYear(){
    return this.year;
}
public int getRank(){
    return this.rank;
}
public String getArtist(){
    return this.artist;
}
public String getTitle(){
    return this.title;
}

public void Song (String Line) {
String[] token = line.split("\t");
title = token[0];
artist = token[1];
year = Integer.parseInt(token[2]);

   }
```

}

Comment: If you want to know whether it works, then I suggest you write a unit test for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't make this method static, because it access object variables: `title, artist, year`

So you need to use a constructor, or pass an object into the method:

```
public Billboard (String Line) {
    String[] token = line.split("\t");
    this.title = token[0];
    this.artist = token[1];
    this.year = Integer.parseInt(token[2]);
}
```

Or

```
public static Billboard parseString(String Line) {
    return parseString(line, new Billboard());
}

public static Billboard parseString(String Line, Billboard billboard) {
    String[] token = line.split("\t");
    billboard.setTitle(token[0]);
    billboard.setArtist(token[1]);
    billboard.setYear(Integer.parseInt(token[2]));
    return billboard;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Song class:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import utils.Utils;

public class Song {

    private String title;
    private String artist;
    private int rank;
    private int year;

    public Song(String title, String artist, int rank, int year){
        this.title = title;
        this.artist = artist;
        this.year = year;
        this.rank = rank;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getArtist() {
        return artist;
    }

    public int getRank() {
        return rank;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public static Song parseLine(String line, String delimiter) {
        String[] parts = Utils.splitLine(line, delimiter);
        return new Song(parts[0], parts[1], Integer.parseInt(parts[2]),Integer.parseInt(parts[3]));
    }

    public static List<Song> readFile(String dataFile) {
        List<Song> lines = new ArrayList<Song>();
        String line = null;


        try{
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(new File(dataFile));
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

            while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                lines.add(parseLine(line, "\t"));
            }

        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return lines;
    }

        @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((artist == null) ? 0 : artist.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + rank;
        result = prime * result + ((title == null) ? 0 : title.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + year;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Song other = (Song) obj;
        if (artist == null) {
            if (other.artist != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!artist.equals(other.artist))
            return false;
        if (rank != other.rank)
            return false;
        if (title == null) {
            if (other.title != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!title.equals(other.title))
            return false;
        if (year != other.year)
            return false;
        return true;
    }


}
```

Utils.splitLine() :

```
public class Utils {

    public static String[] splitLine(String line, String delimiter) {
        if(delimiter.equals("|")){
            delimiter = "\\|";
        }

        if(delimiter.equals(".")){
            delimiter = "\\.";
            }

        String[] rtn = line.split(delimiter);
        for(int i=0;i<rtn.length;i++){
            rtn[i] = rtn[i].trim();
        }

        return rtn;
    }
}
```

Tests:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Test;


public class HelpTest {

    @Test
    public void test_parseLine() {
        // tabs betwen the title artist year and rank
        String line = "Run Runaway  Slade   20  1984";
        Song expected = new Song("Run Runaway","Slade", 20, 1984);
        Song actual = Song.parseLine(line, "\t");   
        assertEquals(expected, actual);

    }

    @Test
    public void test_readFile() {
        String path = "src/testSongData";
        Song song = new Song("Run Runaway","Slade", 20, 1984);
        List<Song> expected = new ArrayList<Song>();
        expected.add(song);
        List<Song> actual = Song.readFile(path);
        assertEquals(expected, actual);

    }

}
```

text file `src/testSongData` used to `readFile()`:

```
Run Runaway Slade   20  1984
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void Song (String Line)
```

Change it to

```
public static Song createSong (String aLine_in)
```

Note the changes:

1. `static` keyword added.
2. method name starts with small letter. (find more suitable name)
3. local variable/method argument starts with small letter. because it's an argument `_in` is prefixed.

You can call static method as follows:

```
Song aSong = Song.createSong("...\t...\t...");
```